# Ajax PHP - ParserError "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición GET con ajax y PHP, pero siempre obtengo el siguiente error:

```
text status=:parsererror, error thrown:=SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Mi petición ajax es la siguiente:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'private/ajax/get_personas.php',
        type:'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('message=:' + data + ', text status=:' + textStatus + ', error thrown:=' +  errorThrown); 
        }
    });
```

El archivo get_personas.php solo contiene las siguientes líneas de código:

```
include('private/connection.php');  
echo json_encode("hello");
```

Y el archivo connection.php

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "12345";
$db = "pruebas";
$port = 3306;

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port);
```

Lo extraño es que si incluyo (copio todo el código) las líneas de código del archivo connection.php en el archivo get_personas.php todo funciona correctamente. Eh tratado de resolver el problema pero no lo eh logrado, espero alguien pueda ayudarme. No quiero tener que agregar todo el código de conexión en cada petición ajax que realice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este error lo dispara jQuery, y ocurre porque estás recibiendo un HTML en vez de un JSON. Por eso es que se menciona el **`<`** dentro de la descripción del error.

> Unexpected token **<** in JSON at position 0

---

Primero, te recomiendo 2 puntos básicos a revisar:

1. ¿Hay espacios antes de iniciar algún script, o cualquier línea que pudiera estar imprimiendo texto que no es un JSON?
   Es importante que no haya ni siquiera una línea en blanco antes de abrir la etiqueta `<?php`, y que la única línea que se imprima sea

   ```
   echo json_encode($texto);
   ```
2. ¿Por casualidad estás usando la etiqueta `<?` en vez de `<?php` para iniciar el código, y están deshabilitadas en el ini?  (aunque ni siquiera se recomienda usarlas).

Si esto no resulta evidente, una posible forma de depurarlo es evaluando el HTML que envía el servidor. Para eso, se puede eliminar la configuración que requiere una respuesta como JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'private/ajax/get_personas.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(textStatus, jqXHR, data);
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('message=:' + data + ', text status=:' + textStatus + ', error thrown:=' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Una vez obtenido, podría distinguirse más fácilmente por qué la respuesta es un HTML.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, gracias a tu consejo pude encontrar el error.