# AJAX, JQuery y JSON en Wordpress: errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estoy intentando usar AJAX en mi sitio de Wordpress y no logro traer datos del servidor.
He reducido mi código a algo super sencillo para ver si encuentro el error y nada!

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_vc_ajax_test', 'vc_ajax_test');
add_action('wp_ajax_vc_ajax_test', 'vc_ajax_test');

function vc_ajax_test(){

    $results = array(
        'success'  => true,
        'html' => 'algo'
        );  
    echo json_encode ($results);
    die();

}

// función jQuery

$( "#ajax-trigger" ).click(function() {
            console.log( '#ajax-trigger clicked!' );
            link = $(this);
            content = 
            id   = link.attr('id');

            console.log( 'id: ' + id );

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : jp.ajax_url,
                type : 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                nonce: jp.nonce,
                data : {
                    action : 'vc_ajax_test',
                    message: 'Button has been clicked!'
                },
                beforeSend: function(){
                    link.html('Cargando ...');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR);
                    console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
                    console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success : function(respuesta) {

                    link.html('#ajax-trigger');
                    $('#ajax-target').html('Debería funcionar: ');

                    console.log('Data:' + respuesta.html);

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

El error aparece automáticamente cuando coloco dataType: 'json'. El tema es que sin eso, haciendo echo la variable pasa como "undefined". Entonces mi lucha es intentar que pase algo del servidor al cliente para leerlo en jQuery, cosa que hasta ahora me ha sido imposible.

> jqXHR: [object Object] textStatus: parsererror errorThrown:
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

¿me ayudan?

Comment: Intenta usando `wp_send_json_success($results);` en lugar del echo

Comment: Hola! No funcionó. Sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Tal vez tu problema es por que estas retornando un HTML en lugar de un Json, Quizás aquí este la respuesta a tu problema: [Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25458/30865)

Comment: Bien, está retornando toda la página en la respuesta... el asunto es que en la función yo hago echo de un array, como puede ser que suceda esto?

Comment: Al final el problema era que tenía mal escrita la url que estaba pasando en los parámetros de ajax. url : jp.ajaxurl (en lugar de url : jp.ajax_url,)